# Send Specific Shortcut Keys from RDP Window to Local Machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-server

We have software installed on our Fat Clients that runs in the background (tray application) and detects a key combination to be activated.

When our users have an RDP window open full screen the key combination for this software is sent to the remote desktop, and not the local machine.

I'm aware that I can send all key combinations to the local desktop, **I don't want to do this.**

Is there a way to send **only the key combinations used by this software** out of the remote desktop and onto the local machine desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, at least not with the native RDP client.  You have 3 options with regards to key combinations.

[image: RDP Client - Local Resources settings]

- **On this computer** - All key combinations stay on the local computer period.
- **On the remote computer** - All key combinations are sent to the remote computer *while the window is active or full screen*.
- **Only when using the full screen** - Key combinations are only sent to the remote computer while it is full screen.

In all cases, it's an all or nothing thing. There's no sub-setting for "only these key combinations".